Extensions of metacyclic groups
A group $G$ is metacyclic if has the following exact sequence
$$1 \to N \to G \to K \to 1$$
where $N$ and $K$ are cyclic groups. In the split extensions, the wikipedia says that direct and semidirect product of metacyclic groups is metacyclic. What about non split extensions? Is it true? I mean, if $N$ and/or $K$ are/is metacyclic, then is also $G$?

Presumably, Wikipedia wouldn't specify the condition that the sequence splits if it hadn't been necessary.

@Arthur I'm not sure since wikipedia does not mention exact sequence, just direct and semidirect product. I think it perhaps can be false since non split extensions do not always have "well behavior" between $N, G, K$, but I cannot find a counterexample.

Where in Wikipedia does it say that "direct and semidirect product of metacyclic groups is metacyclic"? I don't see that (false) claim in the Metacyclic group page.

Probably you missread when the wikipedia says "The direct product or semidirect product of two cyclic groups is metacyclic".

If I understand correctly, you ask whether direct (or semidirect) products of metacyclic groups are metacyclic. This is false. For instance $C_2\times C_2\times C_2$ is a direct product of the metacyclic groups $C_2\times C_2$ and $C_2$.
